# Adobe Creative SDK iOS: Framework CreativeSDKImage requires framework CreativeSDKFoundation but framework CreativeSDKFoundation is not present

Tags: ios, cordova, frameworks, adobecreativesdk

Every-time I tried to run my code is crashes as any-point that I try to initiate the function to call any part of the SDK.

I have included the FoundationSDK in my build process:
[image]

And I have included the reference to SDK in the header file:

[image]

But anytime I run this, I get this error:

`Uncaught exception: Framework CreativeSDKImage requires framework CreativeSDKFoundation but framework CreativeSDKFoundation is not present`

Any ideas?

Comment: Same problem here. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found the solution, the documentation is not very clear.

You have to add the framework `.bundle`s too.

• Locate your CreativeSDKFoundation in Finder
• Go to `AdobeCreativeSDKFoundation.framework/Versions/A/Resources/`
• you'll find `AdobeCreativeSDKFoundationResources.bundle`
• Drag this bundle to your project bundle, in Xcode.

You might do the same for each Creative framework.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, it works. Without knowing this, Adobe is wrong to claim "Integrating the image editor typically takes less than 15 minutes of development time."